# How to send and Mime attachment using PEAR Soap

Tags: php, soap, pear, mime

How do I sent and Soap request with an Mime attachment?

Now I create an Soap_Attachment with

```
$att = new SOAP_Attachment('contentID', $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'] . '; charset=utf-8', $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])
```

but how do I attach this attachment to my request? My request is e.g.

```
$result = $soapClient->call('saveEmployeeXmlData', array(
    'id'    => 'a-key',
    'key'   => '12456865456845',
    'data'  => $xml
), $options);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
$soapClient->getProxy ();
$soapClient->setOpt ( 'Mime', true );
$soapClient->saveEmployeeXmlData ( array (
        'id' => 'a-key',
        'key' => '12456865456845',
        'data' => $att 
) );
```

Comment: I get 'No operation register in WSDL.', and in the documentation of SOAP_Client in PEAR I also can't find a method calles 'register'

Comment: I want to assume that you are using http://pear.php.net/reference/SOAP-0.9.1/SOAP/SOAP_Attachment.html not sure of how your WSDL is structured but can you paste the contented in paste bin let me see

Comment: call `$soapClient->getProxy();` and change `register` to relevant method name .. thats all

Comment: Form what i see its accepting the xml as string not as attachment ..... a WSDL that has attachment would have `mine` attribute see sample : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-soapjax.html

Comment: The XML contains some personal data, and the attachment will be an CV.
So yes, the XML must be sent as an string, and an extra CV will be sent an an Mime Attachment

Comment: Regarding to the docs I need to sent 3 params with method saveEmployeeXmlData: id, key and data (wich is an XML of personal data), and as MimeAttachment an .doc or .docx file (the CV).
I tested this workflow with SoapUI, and that works propper! I only need to convert it to PHP now ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10846/discussion-between-george-boot-and-baba)